# recursive resolution object containing promises

Tags: javascript, object, npm, recursion, promise

I'm looking at a functionality similar to `p-props`, `p-all` npm library but which recursively resolves promises

```
const values = {
    a: () => Promise.resolve(1),
    b: [() => Promise.resolve(2)],
    c: {
        d: () => Promise.resolve(3),
    },
};
console.log(await resolve(values, { concurrency: 2}));
```

What I'm expecting is  `{a: 1, b: [2], c: {d: 3}}` and only 2 promises should be running at a time

I see that this can be accomplished by clubbing together p-all, p-props/p-map and their mappers. But not sure about concurrency. Is there any existing approach to such a requirement?

Comment: ok. So essentially the values needs to be wrapped in a deferred function call. So the library should invoke it and then resolve it. The invocation depends on the concurrency. Essentially something like what p-all does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep track of the pending promises (in a `Set`) and use `Promise.race` to detect when one of those resolves. Then you can execute the next task and add it again to that set, ...etc.

Use recursion to drill down to those tasks, and as promises resolve (using `Promise.all`), rebuild the object structure with the resolved values.

A demo with promises that take varying times to resolve:

```js
function resolveNested(tasks, {concurrency = 2} = {}) {
    const pendingPromises = new Set;
    
    function enqueue(task) {
        if (pendingPromises.size < concurrency) { // We have room to create the promise now
            const promise = task().then(value => {
                pendingPromises.delete(promise);
                return value;
            });
            pendingPromises.add(promise);
            return promise;
        }
        // No room now. Try again when one pending promise has resolved
        return Promise.race([...pendingPromises]).then(() => enqueue(task));
    }
    
    function dfs(item) {
        if (typeof item === "function") return enqueue(item);
        if (Object(item) !== item) return item; // primitive
        // Apply recursion, and collect resolved values:
        const promise = Promise.all(Object.values(item).map(dfs));
        if (Array.isArray(item)) return promise;
        return promise.then(values => // Rebuild object structure
            Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(item).map((key, i) => [key, values[i]]))
        );
    }

    return dfs(tasks);
}

// Some helper functions for a demo:
const elapsed = () => Math.floor((performance.now() - start) / 100) / 10 + " sec";

const delay = async (ms, val) => {
    console.log(`${elapsed()} - Creating promise: delay(${ms}, ${val})`);
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    console.log(`${elapsed()} - Resolved promise: delay(${ms}, ${val})`);
    return val;
};

// Demo:
const values = {
    a: () => delay(1000, "A"),
    b: [() => delay(2000, "b[0]"), () => delay(500, "b[1]")],
    c: {
        d: () => delay(3000, "c.d"),
        lit: "literal",
        e: () => delay( 500, "c.e"),
    },
};

const start = performance.now();
resolveNested(values, { concurrency: 2}).then(console.log);
```

Comment: Adding one more check for primitive types in the dfs could allow things like values = {f: 1, g: [2]} to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `mapper(value, key)` do this

> Receives the current value and key as parameters. If a value is a Promise, `mapper` will receive the value this `Promise` resolves to. Expected to return a `Promise` or value.

```
import pProps from 'p-props';

const values = {
  a: Promise.resolve(1),
  b: [Promise.resolve(2), Promise.resolve(2.1)],
  c: {
    d: Promise.resolve(3),
    e: {
      f: Promise.resolve(4),
      g: {
        h: [Promise.resolve(5), Promise.resolve(5.1)],
      },
    },
  },
};

const createMapper = (value, key) => {
  const mapper = (v, k) => {
    if (Array.isArray(v)) {
      return pProps(Object.fromEntries(v.map((e, i) => [i, e]))).then(
        Object.values
      );
    }
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(v) === '[object Object]') {
      return pProps(v, mapper);
    }
    return v;
  };
  return mapper(value, key);
};

pProps(values, createMapper).then((r) => console.log(JSON.stringify(r)));
```

Output:

```bash
{"a":1,"b":[2,2.1],"c":{"d":3,"e":{"f":4,"g":{"h":[5,5.1]}}}}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pauow9?file=index.ts)

Comment: I thought of writing a mapper, but the problem is that it can't use the shared concurrency. In the original pProps, I could have passed concurrency: 5 and be sure that only 5 promises are getting resolved at a time

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```js
async function recursiveResolve(input) {

  const result = await input;
  if (Array.isArray(result)) {
    return result.map(item => recursiveResolve(input));
  }
  if (typeof result === 'object') {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.toEntries(result).map([k,v] => [k, recursiveResolve(v)]));
  }
  return result;

}
```

Comment: Careful, the `typeof` a `Promise` is also `"object"`

Comment: @Phil wouldn't promises get resolved in the await statement?